# Kubernetes in Docker for Desktop (Windows) is unable to connect to the server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, kubernetes-apiserver

I set up Docker for Desktop (Windows) and enabled Kubernetes in the gui. I am behind a Proxy and added .internal to the no_proxy environmental variable. 
kubectl config get-contexts shows that I am in the docker-desktop context. 
kubectl config view shows the following **config**:

```
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
  name: docker-desktop
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-desktop
    user: docker-desktop
  name: docker-desktop
current-context: docker-desktop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: docker-desktop
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

Now whenever I try to run a command like kubectl cluster-info or kubectl get pod, the following **Error-Message** is shown:

**Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup kubernetes.docker.internal on 160.50.250.20:53: dial udp 160.50.250.20:53: connect: network is unreachable**

Answer (score 3):

As a solution i edited the config file which is in

```
~/.kube/config
```

I replaced "kubernetes.docker.internal" with "localhost"